# Objective C - Manual Array FIFO Queue

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays

Just wondering the best way to create a manual array, without using NSMutalbleArray, I have being researching best possible solutions but without an elegant answer, what do you think, in Objective C what's the best way to create an NSMutableArray style object from scratch?
with a FIFO queue as the final solution, even a basic array structure would be a great hint! thanks,
John

Comment: Either an `id *` or a linked list based solution would work...

Comment: What's wrong with NSMutableArray ?

Comment: If you have the need to bound it, why not just use a normal array and manage push and pop indeces?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Categories on NSMutableArray is the easiest way IMO. I have a category for stacks (LIFO) and queues (FIFO)

Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (QueueStack)
-(id)queuePop;
-(void)queuePush:(id)obj;
-(id)stackPop;
-(void)stackPush:(id)obj;
@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "NSMutableArray+QueueStack.h"

@implementation NSMutableArray (QueueStack)
// Queues are first-in-first-out, so we remove objects from the head
-(id)queuePop {
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if ([self count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    id queueObject = [[[self objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];

    [self removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    return queueObject;
  }
}

// Add to the tail of the queue
-(void)queuePush:(id)anObject {
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    [self addObject:anObject];
  }
}

//Stacks are last-in-first-out.
-(id)stackPop {
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    id lastObject = [[[self lastObject] retain] autorelease];

    if (lastObject)
        [self removeLastObject];

    return lastObject;
  }
}

-(void)stackPush:(id)obj {
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    [self addObject: obj];
  }
}
@end
```

To Make and use a queue:

```
NSMutableArray *queue = [NSMutableArray array];

//Put an item in the queue
[queue queuePush:myObj];

//Retrieve an item, (this will be the first one)
MyCoolObject *myObject = [queue queuePop];
```

Answer (score 3):

Array with FIFO manner:

```
if (mutArr.count == 5) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            [mutArr exchangeObjectAtIndex:j withObjectAtIndex:j+1];
        }
        [mutArr removeObjectAtIndex:4];
        [mutArr addObject:mutDict];
    }else{
        [mutArr addObject:mutDict];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I don't understand the problem with an NSMutableArray, here's a way you could implement a queue using a doubly linked list (Hopefully I got it right, I'm kinda tired ;)):

Note: I'm assuming usage of ARC.

```
//Node.h
@interface Node : NSObject

@property (strong)id value;
@property (strong)Node *previous;
@property (strong)Node *next;


//Node.m
@implementation
@end


/Queue.h
@interface Queue : NSObject

- (void)enqueue:(id)objectToEnqueue;
- (id)dequeue;

@end

//Queue.m
@interface Queue ()
{
    Node *start;
}

@implementation

- (void)enqueue:(id)objectToEnqueue
{
    Node *node = [Node new];
    node.value = objectToEnqueue;

    if (nil == start)
    {
        node.previous = node;
        node.next = node;
        start = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node.previous = start.previous;
        node.next = start;
        start.previous = node;
        start = node;
    }
}

- (id)dequeue
{
    if (nil == start)
        return nil;

    Node *node = start.previous;

    start.previous = start.previous.previous;
    start.previous.next = start;

    id objectToDequeue = node.value;

    return objectToDequeue;

}
@end
```

If you're looking for a way to do that in pure C, maybe this will help you:

[C PROGRAM TO IMPLEMENT A QUEUE](http://sourcecode4u.com/categories/data-structures/98-queue-using-linked-list)